# How to prevent many-to-many class to link to the same objects?

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

In my User model, I've specified this:

```
friends = models.ManyToManyField(
    'self', 
    blank=True, 
    symmetrical=False, 
    through='Relationship')
```

And here's that class I'm using:

```
class Relationship(models.Model):
    person1 = models.ForeignKey(
        User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name="person1")

    person2 = models.ForeignKey(
        User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name="person2")
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('person1', 'person2'),)
```

With `unique_together` I've tried to make many-to-many relations to be one-directional i.e. to prevent creating many-to-many object if the same object with specified keys exist in vice-versa order, but it doesn't work. Also it seems that the relation can't be symmetrical because if I set that attribute to true it's giving me an error which says that with custom class isn't possible.
There's one more thing I wanted to do - prevent creation of a m2m object with foreign keys which are both the same. When searching over the Internet I've found the part of Django documentation which talks about [overriding model functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods), so if I go by that method the result would be:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.person1 == self.person2:
        return
    else:
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My questions are following: Can someone help me with creating symmetrical relation, and is this method above good, or there's some better way to achieve that?

Comment: perhaps you should prevent creating same-persion friends via form validation

Comment: @WenZhu form validation is a nice addition but it can/should never replace model-level validation IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that:

1. you do not want duped relationships
2. a person cannot reference itself
3. a relationship between A and B is the same as B and A and only one should be allowed

Then overriding `unique_together` will enforce 1. And a custom `save()` will enforce 2. and 3.

So both techniques are needed in this case.

An alternative is to use a `pre_save` signal to the same effect. But overriding `save` is simpler and more explicit IMH.O

Comment: Thanks for expressing your opinion. I've figured out now that `unique_together` isn't the solution for preventing creation of a m2m object with the keys in vice-versa order, so I've edited my question above. Also it seems that the relation can't be symmetrical because if I set that attribute to True, then it's giving me an error which says that with custom class isn't possible. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit your question? I am correct to says that you do not want duped relationships and that a person cannot reference itself and that a relationship between A and B is the same as B and A and only one should be allowed?

Comment: Yes, you have guessed right. Sorry for not explaining a bit simpler.